# Creating a Map with only available data elements(values)

Tags: javascript

I have the below arrays:

```
const elements = ['12345', '12346', '12347', '12348', '12349', '12350'];

const fruits = ['Apple', 'Ball'];
```

I am trying to generate a Map, with array: `elements` as key, based on the length of array: `fruits`. And wanted to discard other elements.

So, it should be like:

```
eleFruitMap: { '12345' => 'Apple',
               '12346' => 'Ball'}
```

But, with my implementation, I am getting as:

```
eleFruitMap: { '12347' => 'Apple',
               '12348' => 'Ball',
               '12349' => undefined,
               '12350' => undefined,
}
```

I have tried:

```js
const elements = ['12345', '12346', '12347', '12348', '12349', '12350'];
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Ball'];

let eleFruitMap = elements.slice(fruits.length).map((key, index) => ({
  [key]: fruits[index]
}));
console.log('NEW MAP: ', eleFruitMap);
```

But, all it is doing is - just removing the first element ('12345') from the array: elements and making second element ('12346') as the first key and still keeping 'undefined' values.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: The first argument to `slice()` is the starting index. It should be `elements.slice(0, fruits.length)`

Comment: Your code isn't producing the output you show.

Comment: It is showing it. I can see 'undefined' values from index 2.

Comment: I see that. But there are only 4 total elements, not 6.

Comment: Your slice is going from element 2 to 5, not from 0 to 1. It fills in the values of the first 2, then uses undefined for the next 2.

Comment: Click on Run code snippet and you'll see.

Comment: Also the output you expect is an object with multiple properties, the output you're getting is an array of objects with single properties.

Comment: @Barmar I see what you're saying. My bad, I got the log incorrect in my question. Let me edit it.

Comment: Unless there's a good reason not to, I would map over the shorter array (fruits), and pull in the matching element.

Comment: I was trying 'not' to get all details of the actual map from my work, but, the real array for the fruits contains same/similar/repeated elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `slice(fruits.length)` actually gets your elements array from index 2 and totally the 4 last items. For the first 2 items you have fruits then none. That's why `undefined` for the last 2 items in the result. Use `slice(0, fruits.length)`.

Just read the MDN docs for `Array::slice()`.

Actually you could reduce the fruits array, looks easier and no intermediate array.

```js
const elements = ['12345', '12346', '12347', '12348', '12349', '12350'];
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Ball'];

let eleFruitMap = fruits.reduce((r , fruit, idx) => (r[elements[idx]] = fruit, r), {});
console.log('NEW MAP: ', eleFruitMap);
```